# Only 1 render triggered after 2 setState in onBlur & onFocus in a row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Open the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/c392625/pen/RwapKja), toggle the console.

When using keydown callback to trigger the focus change:

1. click black area to focus the `outside` div.
2. press any **ARROW KEYS** to focus `inside` div
3. render is called **ONCE**

When using click to trigger the focus change:

1. click black area to focus the `outside` div.
2. **press tab** or **click yellow area** to focus `inside` div
3. render is called **TWICE**

In both scenarios, blur & focus events are triggered in a row, why is the render time different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug to react and got an response.
See it here:  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19698